# Number of positive integers $k$ such that there exists a nonnegative integer $m$ with $k + k^m = n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let $a(n)$ be the number of positive integers $k$ such that there exists a nonnegative integer $m$ with $k + k^m = n$.

The sequence begins
$$0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3$$
Let
$$b(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\left\lfloor\log_{i+1}(n-i)\right\rfloor$$

Also
$$c(n)=b(n)-b(n-1)+1$$

I conjecture that $c(n)=a(n+1)$ for $n>0$.

Is there a way to prove it? If the conjecture is true, is it possible to use it to answer the questions posed in [A309978](https://oeis.org/A309978)? The questions are:

- Does there exist $n$ such that $a(n) \geqslant 5$?
- Do there exist examples besides $30$ and $130$ such that $a(n) = 4$?

Comment: Did you check the first 1000 terms $a_n$?

Comment: There is some discussion of this in Dana Mackenzie's paper at https://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g13gift/math/MackenzieDana-GiftExchange-2184-G4G13.pdf although the greater concern of that paper is representations as $k^m-k$. Also, https://oeis.org/A057896 deals with $k^m-k$.

Comment: Not research level. Plus, why the tag "representation theory"?

Comment: I have removed "representation theory" tag. The last 2 questions *may* be of research level, but I'm not sure.

Comment: For clarification (this confused me for a moment): $a(30) = 4$ because $29 + 29^0 = 15 + 15^1 = 5 + 5^2 = 3 + 3^3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula $c(n)=a(n+1)$ is pretty much straightforward, noticing that
$$\lfloor \log_{i+1}(n-i)\rfloor -  \lfloor\log_{i+1}(n-1-i)\rfloor=1\quad\text{iff}\quad n-i=(i+1)^m\text{ for some }m.$$
The latter condition means that $n+1=k+k^m$ with $k:=i+1$.